# How can I run code upon instantiating a class?

Tags: java, object, constructor

How can I run code when a new object is created, without having to perform any separate calls? In other words, how can I define what happens during the creation of an object?

For example:

```
class Apple {
    //code here
}

// ...
Apple banana = new Apple();
// ...
```

How can I automatically run code at the time I call this:

```
Apple banana = new Apple();
```

For example, how can I make one of `Apple`'s methods be called at the time I create the new `Apple`? Coming from Python, I’m looking for something like `__init__`.

Comment: You're looking for [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) it seems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a constructor to your `Apple` class:

```
class Apple {
    public Apple () {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```